# Netplan Interface Disappears on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, netplan, interface

I am running 20.04.1 LTS on an Intel NUC, and my wired Ethernet has just disappeared.  It has been working fine for several months using interface enp3s0 with the following netplan file (/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml):

[image]

However now when I do a `ip addr show` it comes up with "lo" and "wlp2s0":

[image]

I thought somehow the interface got renamed so I edited /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml replacing enp3s0 with wlp2s0 and then executed `sudo netplan apply`.

Now when I request `ip addr show`, this is what I get:

[image]

Any suggestions on where the interface has gone, and how I might get my static Ethernet address back working again?

Below is a screenshot of the BIOS showing both active LAN and WAN under bios version AYAPLCEL.86A.0052.2018.0627.1943.  Not sure how to get any more detail than this about the BIOS Ethernet settings.

[image]

Comment: You're the 2nd NUC user that I've seen to have this problem. Your edit to the .yaml was incorrect, as wlp2s0 is your wireless device. Does the BIOS see your ethernet device? What kernel are you running... `uname -r`? What happens if you boot to an older kernel? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT model # of your NUC.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the attention:    `# uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic
#sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
AYAPLCEL.86A.0052.2018.0627.1943`

NUC Model:  NUC6CAY

Comment: Does your BIOS see the ethernet interface? What happens if you boot to an older kernel? Please see my answer. Try the newer BIOS and report back.

Comment: @heynnema, it would appear from my edit of the post adding the BIOS screenshot that the BIOS does see the ethernet interface (not sure how to get more detailed Ethernet info from the BIOS).  I will have answers about the older kernel and new BIOS once I have implemented those tests.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: You probably should look at dmesg output as well, for any errors related to network drivers failing to load.  The absence of anything in `ip a` output means that the kernel has failed to find or successfully initialize the device.

Comment: The other user that I was helping with this exact same issue on a NUC solved it with the same BIOS update called out in my answer.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**.yaml**

Edit /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml and change the device name back to enp3s0.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

**BIOS**

Intel NUC6CAY

You have BIOS version AYAPLCEL.86A.0052.2018.0627.1943.

There appears to be a newer BIOS available, AYAPLCEL.86A.0066, dated 12/17/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/95078/Intel-NUC-Kit-NUC6CAYS) or [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29319/BIOS-Update-AYAPLCEL-86A-?product=95078).

BIOS Update Instructions are [here](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/29319/eng/NUC-BIOS-Update-Readme.pdf).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model. It covers two different systems.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.